# ssh: execute command on the remote host instead of a login shell

Tags: shell, ssh

I am connecting to `remote-server` from localhost, and I want to execute command on `remote-server`.

works as expected:

```
ssh remote-server "hostname"
remote-server
```

I am confused. Why does this return local hostname, instead of the hostname of remote server?

```
ssh remote-server "print $HOST"
localhost
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second code example:

```
ssh remote-server "print $HOST"
localhost
```

will be flagged by the great [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) tool with the diagnostic [SC2029](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2029):

> Bash expands all arguments that are not escaped/singlequoted. This means that the problematic code is identical to
>
> > ssh host "echo clienthostname"
>
> and will print out the client's hostname, not the server's hostname.
>
> By escaping the $ in $HOSTNAME, it will be transmitted literally and evaluated on the server instead.

By using

```
ssh host "print \$HOST"
```

or

```
ssh host 'print $HOST'
```

you can prevent your *local* shell from expanding host and instead have the shell on `remote-server` expand it.

Comment: Oo, I'm going to have to remember Shellcheck.

Answer (score 6):

Because you're using double-quotes, so the shell evaluates `$HOST` before it executes the command and launches `ssh`, so you send the command "`print localhost`" to the remote server.

Use single quotes instead:

```
shadur@proteus:~$ ssh axiom "echo $HOSTNAME"
shadur@axiom's password:
proteus

shadur@proteus:~$ ssh axiom 'echo $HOSTNAME'
shadur@axiom's password:
axiom
```