# "ssh user@host echo $PATH" gives me local path not remote path

Tags: linux, ssh

why the command

```
ssh user@host echo $PATH
```

or

```
ssh user@host -t echo $PATH
```

return me the path on the local machine and not the path on the remote one?

This means that executing a remote command like

```
ssh user@host command
```

will search for this command on remote machine but using the path defined on the local machine, it's a bit strange behaviour or am I wrong?

Comment: Your local shell is expanding `$PATH` before it even runs ssh. Try quoting it.

Comment: it's the same here. I asked this because I was running a command on a remote machine and it didn't find it even it it was on path (remote machine) and then I find this strange behaviour testing it in this way

Comment: Don’t forget to use ‘single quotes’.  Most shells interpolate variables if you use “double quotes”. (Quotes used here as demonstration, not for emphasis or sarcasm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh: execute command on the remote host instead of a login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402468/ssh-execute-command-on-the-remote-host-instead-of-a-login-shell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command

```
ssh user@host echo $PATH
```

would execute `echo` on the remote host with whatever the value of `$PATH` is locally since the variable is given on the command line unquoted.

To get the *remote* path, make sure that the local shell does not expand the variable:

```
ssh user@host 'echo $PATH'
```

The single quotes around the command stops the local shell from expanding `$PATH`.